# GWT : removeAttribute didnt work?

Tags: html, gwt, video

I am trying to change / remove my video which is in my start.html

```
    <video id="video" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"
    muted="muted" volume="0">
<source
            src="clip0012.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

I am calling this :

```
    Element elem = DOM.getElementById("video_background");
    elem.getFirstChildElement().removeAttribute("src");
elem.getFirstChildElement().setAttribute("src", "clip0022.mp4");
```

i get no error etc. the video clip0012 is still shown , but why?

Comment: There is no element with id "video_background" in your code snippet.

Comment: changed it but nothing happend

Comment: In javascript it is : getElementById('videoSource').src = "X.m4v";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one (See comments for more information in code):

**java:**

```
    //Get old Video Element
    Element oldVideoElement=RootPanel.get("video").getElement();

    //Create a new Video Element
    VideoElement newVideoElement=Document.get().createVideoElement();
    newVideoElement.setId("video");
    newVideoElement.setPreload("auto");
    newVideoElement.setAttribute("autoplay","true");
    newVideoElement.setAttribute("loop","loop");
    newVideoElement.setAttribute("muted","muted");
    newVideoElement.setAttribute("volume","0");

    //Create a new Source Element
    SourceElement sourceElement = Document.get().createSourceElement();
    sourceElement.setSrc("movie.mp4");
    sourceElement.setType("video/mp4");

    //Append new source Element in new video Element
    newVideoElement.appendChild(sourceElement);

    //Append new video element in video div
    RootPanel.get("videoDiv").getElement().appendChild(newVideoElement);

    //remove old video element from its parent
    oldVideoElement.removeFromParent();
```

**html:**

```
<div id="videoDiv">
    <video id="video" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"
        muted="muted" volume="0">
        <source src="clip0012.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
DOM.getElementById("video").setAttribute("src", "clip0022.mp4");
```